# What is the force that drives electrons along the magnetic filaments of galaxies?

Tags: black-hole, galaxy, magnetic-field, filaments

"Milky Way's mysterious filaments have 'older, distant cousins'" https://www.techexplorist.com/milky-ways-mysterious-filaments-older-distant-cousins/54966/?amp=1

Quote from article:
"The seed particles required to form a filament may be provided by the black hole’s jet, but an unknown force must be driving these particles along astounding distances."

Also why do electrons stay together as they move along filaments?

Comment: If an article from a non-science source like techexplorist says "but an unknown force must be driving ..." I wouldn't take that too serious. Electrons move along filaments, as their movement perpendicular to them is restricted by the Lorentz force.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape 
 Farhad Zadeh astrophysicist at Northwestern University says in article:., “Some of them have great length, up to 200 kiloparsecs. That is about four or five times bigger than our entire Milky Way. What’s remarkable is that their electrons stay together on such a long scale. If an electron traveled at the speed of light along the filament’s length, it would take it 700,000 years. And they don’t travel at the speed of light.” So there is some genuine mystery relating to the motion of the electrons

Comment: Perhaps electrons are  displacing each other  from one magnetic field line to another nearby